# passing through php variable to R and retrieve back variable from R to php

Tags: php, r

I have a variable in php $number and im trying to pass it to R using the exec function . In my R script' the function returns a variable and I want it to be put in the php variable
for example:
in php I have:
$number=5
what can I write in my Rscrit so I can output from the php file number+1?

my php code is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $number = $_POST['nbeds'];

    //execute R script from shell
    exec("Rscript testinR.R $number", $output);

    echo $output;

    }
    ?>
```

my R script:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

## Input Simulation parameters

number<-as.integer(args[1])   ## number of beds
return number+1
```

Comment: I believe it is not possible to return a value from the `exec` function. What you may do is make the r script save the value into a file and read from that in your php.